# Git update master from some branch

Tags: git, git-branch

While I'm in a branch B1 can I update the master from remote while staying in B1?
I.e. not doing

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout B1
```

But something shorter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to get your local master updated without leaving your local branch by:

```
git pull origin master:master
```

What this command does is to pull the remote master and update the local master.

Generally `git pull origin` pulls all the branches in `origin`. It's possible to get one single branch pulled by `git pull origin <remote-branch>`. Actually the last parameter is a [refspec](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec).

A *refspec* follows the format *src:dst*. In the case of `git-pull`, *src* refers to a remote branch and *dst* to a local branch. `git pull origin master`, will just pull the remote master but won't update the local one. `git pull origin master:master`, will pull the remote master and update the local one.

Comment: An important caveat here is that the `pull` will only succeed if it will result in a fast-forward merge. If your local master and remote master have diverged then your local master will remain unchanged, though Git should notify you of this.

Comment: And if there is no local change, there should not be any need to update the local branch. Remote-tracking reference `origin/master` update is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You run:

```
git fetch --all
```

or

```
git remote update
```

After that, the remote `master` will in remote-tracking branch `origin/master`, you will be able to see its progress just like it were the local branch `master`. You can choose a time to merge/rebase the local `master` later.

Explanation: most probably you have a pair of remote-tracking branch `origin/master` and local branch `master`. `master` starts from from `origin/master` at some moment and contains local changes. `git pull` (1) updates `origin/master` and (2) merge or rebase the local modifications with `origin/master` progress. (1) can be done by `git fetch` I recommended, and (2) in current implementation requires checking out `master` anyway, even if the changes are trivial to merge.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, the command `git pull origin master:master` doesn't work with git version `2.37.2`, or I should say, it did but, too much.

In fact the last command `(git pull origin master:master)` does three differents things :

1. It updates the branch `master` : I mean it does the same job as if you were on the branch `master` and did `git pull`. In other words, it's equivalent to `git checkout master && git pull`
2. Then, I merge the branch `master` into your current branch `B1` (the name you gave in the question).
3. And finally, depending on your merge politic (`rebase=true`, `rebase=false`, `fast-forward`, `--ff-only`), It would create a new commit on your current branch `(B1)`. Notes well that point : It would create a new commit on your ***current branch (B1)***, which is different of the branch `master`

So I propose another command instead :

`git fetch --force --update-head-ok --verbose origin master:master`

Run `git fetch --help` to get more informations about the options `--update-head-ok` and `--force`.

Hope it helps :)